# Use Magento opConfig.reloadPrice() with jQuery and Custom options

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I am trying to use the Magento `reloadPrice()` with jQuery to refresh the price. I have a configurable product with custom options. Without jQuery, the `SELECT` code for the option is :

```
<select id="select_281" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" name="options[281]" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
<option value="0"></option>
<option rel="1" price="0" value="275"></option>
<option rel="2" price="0" value="276"></option>
</select>
```

With jQuery I remove the Prototype `onchange` code and try to calculate the price for my option (say $50) :

```
jQuery('#select_281').removeAttr('onchange').change(function(){

//Price of the option to add to a basic price of the conf product
price = 50;

optionsPrice.changePrice('opConfig', price);
optionsPrice.reload();

});
```

Price of the configurable product: `$150`.

Add an option (`SELECT`): we add `$50`.

The new price `$200` is displayed  in the product page, But not in the cart page : the cart page displays just $150 which is not correct.

Someone can help?

Best regards,
COM.

Answer (score 1):

The reloadPrice() cant change any price serverside.
So we solved this issue by using  2 observers : `checkout_cart_product_add_after` observer to change the price the first time the product is added to the cart, and `checkout_cart_update_items_after` observer to change the price for each item in the cart (when user click the **"Modify cart"** button on cart page).

The code here tested for configurable products with 2 custom options numberOfColors and engravingType. For each couple *numberOfColors/engravingType* we have tierprices stored in special MySQL table, we may change price with a custom price. Each simple product has its tierPrices.

```
<code>//checkout_cart_product_add_after observer
   public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        $productType = $product->getTypeID();
        $price = 100;//Unit price of product without engraving, 100 for example

        //Unit price with engraving, depending of 2 custom options of configurable product
        if($productType == 'configurable'){
            //get custom options of config here
            .
            .
            $engravingPrice = 1.2;//Get unit price with engraving from a special MySQL table
            $finalUnitPrice = $price + $engravingPrice;//Final custom price

            //Modify the price
            $item->setCustomPrice($finalUnitPrice);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalUnitPrice);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }
    }

    //checkout_cart_update_items_after observer
    public function modifyCartItems(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        foreach ($observer->getCart()->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item ) {
            if ($item->getParentItem()) {$item = $item->getParentItem();}
            $productType = $product->getTypeID();
            $productType = $product->getTypeID();
            $price = 100;//Unit price of product without engraving

            //Unit price with engraving, depending of 2 custom options of configurable product
            if($productType == 'configurable'){
                .
                .
                $engravingPrice = 1.2;//Get unit price with engraving from a special MySQL table
                $finalUnitPrice = $price + $engravingPrice;//Final custom price

                //Modify the price for the item
                $item->setCustomPrice($finalUnitPrice);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalUnitPrice);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            }
        }
    }</code>
```

But.....one problem remains : on the cart page, when user clicks the link "Edit" to edit the product in product page so he can change quantity, ...and click the **"Update cart"** button, this update button does not read the checkout_cart_product_add_after to refresh price.

Dont't know how to force this **"Update cart"** action to process the code in `checkout_cart_product_add_after` observer? Is this code executed just the first time the product is added to the cart?

Thanks.

COM